# WebGL Publishing Error on Ubuntu 20.04 and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, publishing, unity-webgl

I am currently working on the Unity Learn Junior Programmer course, and I am starting to run into issues publishing my Unit final. The final project is to post a modded version of a cube rotation file on Unity Play via WebGL, but every time that I try to build the project, it fails. This has been going on for the past week or so. Every time, I get the following error:

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.SetupAndStart(ExecuteContext context, Boolean asyncMode) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 423
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.ExecuteAsync(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller, Boolean asyncMode) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 299
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Shell/Shell.cs:line 355
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/CppProgramBuilder.cs:line 334
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/ParallelFor.cs:line 78
```

I already have the WebGL publisher installed and the build setup switched to WebGL, so do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does your path to the project contain any special characters? I had this issue (on windows though) that my user name contained an umlaut (`ö`) which led to exactly this error when building for WebGL .. it was fixed when I simply moved the project out of my user folder ...

Comment: Not as far as I am aware of. It's home/downloads/Create With Code 1/Create With Code 1 Final

Comment: Have you tried folder names without spaces? ;)

Comment: No, I have not. Unfortunately, I just got off for the weekend, and I cannot see if that fixes it until Monday.

Comment: Okay, I just tried it again with fixing the file names on the folders into being just lowercase letters (with no spaces or numbers) and it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that is a known issue which will not be fixed according to Unitys bug-tracker:

[See Issue here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linux-editor-webgl-build-always-fails-with-system-dot-componentmodel-dot-win32exception-2-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

It suggests though that upgrading your Unity version to 2021.2.0b5 or higher might fix the issue as it is marked as "not reproducible" with said versions.